# php preg_replace specific sentence problem

Tags: php

```
$string = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

<h2>example</h2>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

example

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

';
```

I have a variable like above and I want to remove the mutable word "example". But if it ends with a line skip, I should do it.

The code below is not working for me.

```php
$new_string = preg_replace('@^'.preg_quote('example').'\r\n$@si','',$string);
```

**I want you to give me this.**

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

<h2>example</h2>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I should do it" -- do what?

Comment: Please show the desired result.

Comment: @Barmar If the word ends with a line skip, I should remove it. I have to specify the word in preg_replace.

Comment: The line break may be just `\n`, not `\r\n`. Try using `\r?\n` to make the carriage return optional.

Comment: So you don't want to remove all `example`, just the ones with a blank line after them?

Comment: @Barmar Please look at the question again.

Answer (score 1):

Add `?` after `\r` to make it optional, so it will work with both Unix and Windows newlines.

Use the `m` flag to make `^` and `$` match beginning/end of lines, not just the string. The `s` flag is for making `.` match newlines.

The last argument to `preg_replace()` should be `$string`, not `$new_string`.

```
$new_string = preg_replace('@^'.preg_quote('example').'\r?\n$@mi','',$string);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/orTi29)

Comment: Try the code, "example" is not removed.

Comment: I did try it, I've added a link to a demo.

Comment: I'm trying on windows wamp. However, I see that it has not been removed. I think we're making a mistake somewhere. (probably related to windows line skip character)

Comment: Sorry, don't know why it's not working for you. I don't have Windows so I can't test there.

Comment: Watch out for extra whitespace at the end of the lines.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the code from the demo as it is. It should also be removed in the blank line that replaces the word when it is removed.

Comment: Hey this did my job, \r\n?|\n. However, there is a small problem that the blank line is not removed.

Comment: If you want to remove the blank line as well, use `\r?\n\{2}` to match both of them.